# Java code to parse an unknown xml, modify content of some nodes and copy it to an output xml

Tags: java, xml, sax

I want to parse an unknown xml, modify the values of certain nodes and then copy the structure to an output. I am not sure how can I proceed. Please assist.

So far I am here, but not sure if I should continue with same approach. Please assist.

```
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                       String qName) throws SAXException {

    if(tmpElementName.equals(qName)){
        System.out.print("<"+tmpElementName+">");
        /**
         * Retrive attributes from HashMap
         */

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet : tmpAtrb.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Attribute Name :"+ entrySet.getKey() + "Attribute Value :"+ entrySet.getValue());
        }
        System.out.print(tmpElementValue);
        System.out.println("</"+tmpElementName+">");
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    tmpElementValue = new String(ch, start, length) ;
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for XSLT to me.

Comment: You need to describe the concrete problem. In general you'll find that doing transformations like this in XSLT is a lot more flexible than doing it in Java code, and of course XSLT can be readily invoked from Java. XSLT will take care of many of the mundane tasks: for example your Java code snippet forgets the detail that special characters in attribute values need to be escaped; details  like that tend to make Java code either very bloated, or (more often than not) incorrect.